# How can I obtain public transport data for Hong Kong / Shenzhen?

Tags: data-request, transportation

I am going to develop an offline transport mobile app around my region (Hong Kong / Shenzhen) but I cannot find any [GTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Transit_Feed_Specification) (General Transit Feed Specification) data available on the web. How can I obtain a set, or generate one myself by using other open data?

Answer (score 3):

- According to reply by Hong Kong government at http://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/201712/13/P2017121300423p.htm , they expect to have a GTFS or API for transit data in Hong Kong available in late 2018.
- Meanwhile, you can look at https://maps.google.com/landing/transit/cities/index.html and see info of each of those transport mode being linked for Hong Kong. For Shenzhen, the URL linked a commercial provider that you can pay to gain access for.
- You can also check sites like www.minibus.hk , evchk.wikia.com , and other sites for related info.
- Kowloon Bus have some more info in their app, which if I recall correctly, their api are being reverse engineered by other apps for access?